# Xcode 6 error - Cannot find OpenGL/gl.h

Tags: xcode, macos, opengl, header-files, command-line-tool

I'm using the Command Line Tools, and getting an error telling me it can not find OpenGL/gl.h

I have the frameworks included, and targeted for the product. Any idea why this is happening? I looked at the frameworks, and I see the header files.

I'm on OS X 10.9.5

Comment: What exactly are the command line options you use for compiling?

Comment: I'm just using whatever the default options are, for the C++ Command Line Tools in Xcode.